# Run a method after the other method finished in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have a hide method.  What I want is, after this hide method finishes, then the other method will run. How can I do that in Jquery ?

For example

```
$('.panel').hide(400);

$('.panel2').fadeIn(400);
```

I want to run second line after the first one finished.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check completion of multiple ajax requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719785/how-to-check-completion-of-multiple-ajax-requests)

Comment: You can provide a callback function to `hide` which will execute when it is finished. RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/hide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hide` method supports callback function parameter:

```
$('.panel').hide(400, function() { $('.panel2').fadeIn(400); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.when(function(){
    $('.panel').hide(400);
}).then(function(){
    $('.panel2').fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to run "panel2" after "panel". Otherwise, good answer. Edited it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when(function1()).then(function2());
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the below link, the hide function can have a call back function

http://api.jquery.com/hide/